# How to send Nested Array parameter using alamofire's Multipart form data

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, alamofire, multipartform-data

How to send this parameter to multipart

```
    let dictionary = [
        "user" :
            [
                "email" : "\(email!)",
                "token" : "\(loginToken!)"
        ],
        "photo_data" :[
            "name" : "Toko Tokoan1",
            "avatar_photo" : photo,
            "background_photo" : photo,
            "phone" : "0222222222",
            "addresses" :[[
                "address" : "Jalan Kita",
                "provinceid" : 13,
                "cityid" : 185,
                "postal" : "45512"
                ]],
            "banks" :[[
                "bank_name" : "PT Bank BCA",
                "account_number" : "292993122",
                "account_name" : "Tukiyeum"
                ]]

        ]

    ]
```

I tried this below code but I can't encode value (which in NSDic) to utf 8

```
        for (key, value) in current_user {
            if key == "avatar_photo" || key == "background_photo"{
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, name: key) // value error because its NSDic
            }else{
             multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, name: value) // value error because its NSDic
            }

        }
```

`value` in append body part cannot be use because it's NSDictionary not string. How the right way to put that parameter in multipartformdata?

Answer (score 1):

It is allowed to have nested multiparts.

> The use of a Content-Type of multipart in a body part within another multipart entity is explicitly allowed. In such cases, for obvious reasons, care must be taken to ensure that each nested multipart entity must use a different boundary delimiter.

[RFC 1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

So you have to do the same you did on the outer loop: Simply loop through the contents of the dictionary generating key-value pairs. Obviously you have to set a different part delimiter, so the client can distinguish a nested part change from a top-level part change.

Maybe it is easier to send the whole structure as application/json.

Comment: `Maybe it is easier to send the whole structure as application/json.` Yes.